# Get element of nonpermanent nested child component

Tags: angular, angular5, autofocus

I have a parent Component, that after some actions will call a child component after an ngIf returns true, and this child component has an Input element that I want to focus.  Because the child component is not instantiated when the parent is, using ViewChild doesn't seem to be working for me.  I am getting close to a good strategy to focus this input with a service, but actually managing to get a reference to this input when needed I am finding to be difficult.

Comment: Did you try focusing on the input element onInit() of the child component?

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the *autofocus* attribute of the input.

```
<input ... autofocus="true">
```

If that doesn't work, then you can create a directive that will force the input to receive focus after the DOM element is created. Here is a directive that I've been using and it has the option to delay the setting of the focus by JS digests which is handy for some difficult component arrangements.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[ui-focus]'
})
export class FocusDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    /**
     * The number of JavaScript digestions to complete before setting focus.
     */
    @Input()
    public focusDelay: string | boolean | number = 0;

    /**
     * Conditionally control if focus should be set.
     */
    @Input()
    public focusEnabled: boolean = true;

    private counter: number;

    public constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (Boolean(this.focusEnabled)) {
            this.counter = this.focusDelay === true ? 1 : parseInt(this.focusDelay + '', 10);
            this.setFocus();
        }
    }

    private setFocus() {
        if (this.counter <= 0) {
            (<HTMLElement>this.el.nativeElement).focus();
        } else {
            this.counter--;
            window.setTimeout(() => this.setFocus());
        }
    }
}
```

You can then assign the directive to the input control.

```
<input ... ui-focus>
```

You shouldn't have to do anything more complicated than this (i.e. no need for a service).

Comment: I have tried out the autofocus property, but the situation is slightly more complicated in that this input can appear and reappear multiple times, and autofocus does not seem to work after the first instance.  I will give some of these other tricks a try and see.